# JAVASCRIPT - FETCH API not displaying Output

Tags: javascript, html, integration

I am just trying to fetch an API data and display the same using the JavaScript Code.. as here.. I am not receiving any Output, The Output is Completely Blank as of Now .. Can you Please check if I have defined any Variable Wrongly.

The API links as here: http://vmaffluence.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?category=website,

```js
'use strict';

function createNode(element) {
  return document.createElement(element);
}

function append(parent, el) {
  return parent.appendChild(el);
}

var ul = document.getElementById('authors');
var url = 'http://vmaffluence.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?category=website';
fetch(url).then(function(resp) {
  return resp.json();
}).then(function(data) {
  var authors = data.results;
  return authors.map(function(website) {
    span.innerHTML = website.id;
    append(li, span);
    append(ul, li);
  });
})['catch'](function(error) {
  console.log();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: green;
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #5a5a5a;
  }
  li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    li {
      flex-basis: 40%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      align-items: center;
      span {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #5a5a5a;
        text-align: center;
      }
      img {
        margin: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Checking API Codes</h1>
<ul id="authors"></ul>
```

Comment: `data` is an array not an object with a property `results`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it going using jQuery.  If you are not using jQuery, you will need to look up how to create the li and span blocks programatically.

```
var ul = $("#authors");

var url = 'http://vmaffluence.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?category=website';

fetch(url).then(function(resp) {
    return resp.json();
}).then(function(data) {
    return data.map(function(website) {
        console.log('INFO - adding website id: [' + website.id + ']');

        var li = $("<li>");
        var span = $("<span>").html(website.id);

        li.append(span);
        ul.append(li);          
    });
})['catch'](function(error) {
    console.log('ERROR - ' + error);
});
```

If you want to use jQuery, you can download the framework from their site and include it via

```
<script src="..." type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It may be more that you are looking for and you can lookup another way to replace the $(...) lines.  I don't know how to do it without jQuery, because I use jQuery.  You don't have to.  You may be able to do something like (don't know):

```
x.innerHtml = "<li><span>" + website.id + "</span></li>";
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks .. Can you Please help me in sending the complete code .. As still I am not able to get the desired result in the HTML Front end.. Request you to share the complete HTML Coding ..with the Jquery Code..